# DJ mixer play through audio interface

Tags: audio, mixer

I have a numark mixtrack pro which has rca outputs. how can i get it to play through the audio interface (focusrite scarlett)? i need this to happen as i cannot directly connect to the speakers. I have already tried linking the mixer to the mic input but this sounded terrible. 
thank you

Comment: Which focusrite scarlett do you have? Did you try turning the gain down enough so that the input was not distorting?

Comment: Sounds like you need an attenuator.  There are these: https://www.amazon.com/Harrison-Labs-Line-Level-Attenuator-x/dp/B0006N41B0 Plug them in the back of the mixtrack, then the RCA cable into them.  There's also the issue of balanced vs. unbalanced, but this is worth a try.

Comment: Doesn't your interface have line inputs? RCA is generally -20 to -10dBv which would be fine for line, but way over-power for mic without the aforementioned attenuator. It would also solve the unbalancing issue.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the specs for the Numark the RCA outputs are sending at line level so you should be able to take the output from the RCA and send it into the Focusrite using the line level inputs. You would use RCA to 1/4in cables and set the Focusrite switches to Line Level. Start with the gain rolled all the way off, and bring the levels up as needed.

EDIT:  I forgot about the Focusrite Scarlett Solo, which only has one line input.  If this is the interface you have then you won't be able to use it directly with the RCA outputs of the Numark, which is two channels out.

Sweetwater has a good explanation of [Audio Signal Levels](https://www.sweetwater.com/insync/understanding-signal-levels-audio-gear/) and there are many other tutorials available online.

According the the Numark guide, the RCA output 1 is controlled by the Master Mix from your software, so make sure the levels aren't too high there also. Depending on which model Numark you have, the RCA 2 output is the CUE channel in your software, and is also the mix going to the headphones output.

Unless you are using the Focusrite for recording, you might consider getting a different solution to connect to your speakers, such as a mini mixer or switch-box depending on why you can't connect to them directly from the Numark.

EDIT:  The RCA outputs are mono right and left, so if you want to send to a single line input, you'll need something that can mix the two channels into a single mono.

Comment: right i have an rca to aux cable which i used plugging a 6.35 mm jack so it would go into the audio interface. it sounded bad as it was only carrying the stereo information (no vocals, kick and sub were almost completely gone) . do i need separate rca to 6.35mm cables and then can i set them to play the two as mono and stereo then? and yes i wasn't clipping

Comment: The RCA output is mono output, Red is right, White is left. If you have the Focusrite 2iX series that has two or more inputs, you would plug each RCA output into a separate channel on the Focusrite. If you only have the Solo, then you will need to get a mini-mixer that can send a summed mono output.

Comment: @DigitalTek Sounds like the same unbalanced-output-to-balanced-input problem as in this question: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/85939/no-sound-is-coming-to-focusrite-scarlett-2i2-when-connected-to-emulated-output-o

Comment: Okay thank you i wasnt sure if it was mid / side. as i have the 2i2 would two rca to xlr or two rca to quater inch jacks work ?
https://www.amazon.co.uk/Cable-Phono-Stereo-Connection-Microphone/dp/B07HBY639F/ref=asc_df_B07HC6138P/?tag=googshopuk-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=310886142184&hvpos=1o2&hvnetw=g&hvrand=10158406011971521550&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9045062&hvtargid=pla-694728600206&th=1

Comment: You want RCA to 1/4 inch jacks.